# how json array iteration can be done?

Tags: javascript, html, json

my json array is like that which was received in html page how it can be display in a table ? means iteration .plz help? i am new .

```
[
    {"studentId":"1001259101","firstName":"RAKESH","lastName":"DALAL","year":"2012","course":"BSC"},
    {"studentId":"1001259101","firstName":"RAKESH","lastName":"DALAL","year":"2012","course":"BSC"},
    {"studentId":"1001259101","firstName":"RAKESH","lastName":"DALAL","year":"2012","course":"BSC"}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This site is pretty good about helping you when you try something and get stuck.  But writing your code from scratch is your own job.

Comment: This isn't a tutorial or code writing service. You should be able to find numerous tutorials to help get you started and come back when you have legitimate code problems

Comment: @Nira http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array and display it in a table:

```
var jsonObject = [
    {studentId: "1001259101", firstName: "RAKESH", lastName: "DALAL", year: "2012", course: "BSC"},
    {studentId: "1001259101", firstName: "RAKESH", lastName: "DALAL", year: "2012", course: "BSC"},
    {studentId: "1001259101", firstName: "RAKESH", lastName: "DALAL", year: "2012", course: "BSC"}
];

var output = "<table>";
for (var i = 0, len = jsonObject.length; i < len; i++) {
    var line = jsonObject[i];
    output += "<tr>";
    output += "<td>" + line.studentId + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + line.firstName + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + line.lastName + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + line.year + "</td>";
    output += "<td>" + line.course + "</td>";
    output += "</tr>";
}
output += "</table>";

document.getElementById(...).innerHTML = output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all JSON is (JavaScript Object Notation). Same JS, just a litlte bit different syntax for object notation.

You need to use AJAX in order to receive JSON data from other file, just have a look:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myJSON.json"; // your JSON text file

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var myResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        display(myResponse); // send array to function
    }
}

xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.send(null);

function display(arr) {
    var myTable = "<table>"; // create a table variable

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // loop through array
        myTable += "<tr>";
        myTable += "<td>" + arr[i].studentId + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + arr[i].firstName + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + arr[i].lastName + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + arr[i].year + "</td>";
        myTable += "<td>" + arr[i].course + "</td>";
        myTable += "</tr>";
    }

    myTable += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("myAwesomeTable").innerHTML = myTable; // display the final result in to html
}
```

1. Use AJAX in order to open your JSON text file, it could be .txt, .json and etc.
2. Use JSON.parse() to convert your JSON text to Array
3. Send that Array to function
4. Create a table and hold everything in variable like a text
5. Loop through array
6. Display your table in to html